# Swift Thread issues

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, timer

I have a function where I download a picture from internet and I put it inside a UIImage, it also adds a website to the picture (UIButton). The Urls are stored in my DB and I store them in an Array. Then I generate a random number to get an index and use it to download the picture. I run the code in my viewDidLoad and it shows the picture and if I click it, it opens the webpage. I am also using a timer to repeat this function every 5 seconds so I was expecting it to display a different picture and website.

Unfortunately it keeps displaying the same picture (webpage is changed) and once in a while it changes the picture, but in console this message is displayed **"This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes."**

What can I do to make this function work properly? I thank you all in advance. my code is the following

```
func descargaPicture(){

    do {

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let miCIudad = defaults.object(forKey: "ciudad") as! String

        let query = tblAd.filter(ciudad == miCIudad)

            for infoAd in try conn.db!.prepare(query) {
                //Guardar en arreglos
                if(imagen.contains(infoAd[fotoAd]!)) {
                    print("ya existe")
                } else {
                    imagen.append(infoAd[fotoAd]!)
                }

                if(web.contains(infoAd[webAd]!)){

                } else {
                web.append(infoAd[webAd]!)
                }
            } //Termina for

        //-------------------------Descarga foto Internet-------------------------------
        /*
         Este proceso es similar a los anteriores, lo que hacemos es, después de obtener la imagen de nuestra BD, procedemos a hacer una petición para descargar la imagen del internet, así para poder después usarla como banner/Ad en determinadas Views, por lo que este bloque de código se encuentra presente en unas pocas clases de nuestro proyecto.
         */
        let numero = imagen.count-1

        if numero <= 0 {
            print("El array esta vacio")
            return
        }

        else {

        var filtro = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numero)+1))

            if imagen[filtro] != "" {
                let picture = URL(string: self.imagen[filtro])!
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: picture) {(data, response, error) in
                    if let e = error {
                print("Erro al descargar la imagen: \(e)")
                    }
                    else {
                        self.imagenAd.image = nil //-----------
                        if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                            print("Descargando foto, respuesta: \(res.statusCode)") //Da 200 como resp.
                            if let imageData = data {
                                let imagen = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

                                self.imagenAd.image = imagen
                                self.webSite = self.web[filtro]

                                }
                                else {
                                print("No se puede obtener imagen")
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                            print("No se obtiene respuesta del servidor")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    downloadPicTask.resume()

                    }

                else {
                print("Es NIL")
                return
                }

            } //Cerramos el else definitivo
            //--------------------/Descarga foto Internet ------------------------------
        } //do

        catch {
        //Errores
        }

}
```

Comment: I also tried with `DispatchQueue.main.async {functionName}` in my viewDidLoad but nothing changed. Same picture is displayed.

Comment: Calling the function from main thread is not going to help. Inside your function after getting response grab main thread and do UI changes there.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed that :) the image changes, but not at the same time as the Timer repeats.For example, I set the timer for every second and the picture is changed within 1 and 3 seconds, sometimes more, sometimes less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. You should do all UI related tasks on main thread. 
Get hold of the main thread using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //your UI Changes go here
}
```

And do all your UI Changes in this code block after getting the response.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking your time for answering my question. I put my "imageAd.image" code in the code you gave me. It changes the displayed picture but not at the same time the Timer calls the function. For example, I set the timer for every second and the picture is changed within 1 and 3 seconds, sometimes more, sometimes less. how can I fix it?

Comment: You are downloading the image. Its going to take time based on size. I would suggest to use some caching library. SDWebImage is very good at this.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I will try what you said. Only One more question, let´s say I have to call the function every 15 seconds. Will the image present the same delay issue??

Comment: I also set you answer as accepted, thank you again for helping me.

Comment: Yes. Even if you try to call function every 15 secs its going to take time. Because its insider your function that you are loading the image. I would suggest to use SDWebImage and use some default image. When the response comes back update the image to downloaded one. This is what you will find in most apps.

Comment: Ok, got it. I will!